# 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'setEchoMod'(проблема решена)

Tags: python, pyqt5, password

не работает код, выдаёт ошибку из заголовка

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from qline import Ui_MainWindow

class win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(win, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('Hi man')
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(10)
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.setEchoMod(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet('color: rgb(28, 43, 255);')
        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(28, 43, 255);')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = win()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Проблемная вот эта строка

```
self.ui.lineEdit_3.setEchoMod(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
```

Что делать?

Comment: Посмотреть в документации и увидеть `setEchoMode`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#echoMode-prop :) Лучше удалите ваш вопрос, это простая опечатка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас опечатка:`setEchoMod` вместо `setEchoMode`.
Вот так правильнo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from qline import Ui_MainWindow

class win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(win, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('Hi man')
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(10)
        self.ui.lineEdit_3.setEchoMod(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.ui.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.ui.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet('color: rgb(28, 43, 255);')
        self.ui.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(28, 43, 255);')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = win()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```